# TypeScript complains when using `includes()` on enum value

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

**Update: This was just a typo, I had used [] instead of () in a function call.**

What is wrong here? I'm trying to find an enum value in an array of that enum type. But TS Complains as you can see.

```
export enum LearningStageType {
  FUEL_DOOR_OFFSET = 'FUEL_DOOR_OFFSET',
  VEHICLE_INFO = 'VEHICLE_INFO',
  POSITIONING = 'POSITIONING',
  CYCLE_DRY_RUN = 'CYCLE_DRY_RUN',
  FINISH = 'FINISH',
}

// Type of `status` used below
export interface LearningStatus {
  vehicleId: string;
  licensePlate: string;
  countryCode: ISO3166a2CountryCode;
  // ...
  allowedStages?: LearningStageType[];

}

// Type of `stage` in code below
export type LearningStage = {
  stageType: LearningStageType;
  instructionText: string;
  instructionImage?: ImageSourcePropType;
  title: string;
  subtitle?: string;
  mainComponent: React.FC<LearningStageProps>;
  isAllowed?(status: LearningStatus, settings: LearningSettings): boolean;
};

// My code
  const stage = stages[previousStageType];

  if (skipValidation) {
    return stage;
  }
  if (stage.isAllowed) {
    return stage.isAllowed(status, settings) ? stage : null;
  }
  // The line that makes TS complain:
  if (status.allowedStages?.includes[stage.stageType]) {
    return stage;
  }
  return null;
```

TS Error:

```
(property) LearningStatus.allowedStages?: LearningStageType[] | undefined
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'LearningStageType' can't be used to index type '(searchElement: LearningStageType, fromIndex?: number | undefined) => boolean'.
  Property '[LearningStageType.FUEL_DOOR_OFFSET]' does not exist on type '(searchElement: LearningStageType, fromIndex?: number | undefined) => boolean'.ts(7053)
```

Comment: Includes takes a callback detector function

Comment: `includes` is not an array. You can't use `[]` on it. Did you mean `includes(stage.stageType)` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it was a typo I didn't see after a long day of coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using the `includes` method in a non-standard way. Instead of calling it like a function, you are using square bracket notation which is incorrect. The correct way to use the `includes` method would be as follows:

```js
if (status.allowedStages?.includes(stage.stageType)) {
  return stage;
}
```

In this way, the TypeScript compiler will recognize includes as a method and will not give an error.

Comment: Thank you, I quickly noticed it was a typo :) *facepalm*